# Custom Listview display all items in one row

Tags: c#, wpf, listviewitem

I have a custom `ListView` that instead of displaying each item in separate row, displays all items in the same row, the result looks like:

[image]

There are currently 2 items in that `ListView` but I can't get `ListView` to display each item in separate row. 
Here there is the `ListView` code:

```
 <ListView BorderThickness="0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListItemStyle}" Name="LoginRegister">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="2">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="/Application/Resources/Icons/user.png" Width="20" Grid.Column="0" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Foreground="{StaticResource BaseGrey}"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                TextAlignment="Left"
                                FontWeight="Light"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding UserName}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Here is the `ListViewItemStyle`:

```
 <Style x:Key="ListItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#ecf0f1" />
                </Style.Resources>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ecf0f1" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

What could be the reason of the behavior?

Comment: Tried it out. Working for me.

Comment: Did you set the itemssource by code?

Comment: No, just did this: `LoginRegister.Items.Add(new UserItem() {UserName = "Szabolcs Dézsi"}); LoginRegister.Items.Add(new UserItem() {UserName = "John Doe"});` where `UserItem` is `public class UserItem { public string UserName { get; set; } }`. And it looks like this: http://imgur.com/eQyqcQD My image is from the net (16x16)

Comment: Are you certain it's displaying both items? Your horizontal scrollbar doesn't look small enough to indicate there is another item to the right. Maybe your second item was added to the source but your control was not updated.

Comment: @TreeTree yes there are 2 items, mvallejo and esantana are separated items each

Comment: @Misters Can you edit your question to include a screenshot that shows both items on the same row? For sanity's sake.

Comment: @TreeTree Ok, checked and turns out you are right, There was only 1 items in the list

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show items in separated rows, then you should create `RowDefinitions`, rather then `ColumnDefinitions`:

```
<ListView BorderThickness="0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListItemStyle}" Name="LoginRegister">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="2">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="/Application/Resources/Icons/user.png" Width="20" Grid.Row="0" />
                        <TextBlock
                            Foreground="{StaticResource BaseGrey}"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            TextAlignment="Left"
                            FontWeight="Light"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding UserName}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: @Misters feel free to ask any question. Do I understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, the issue is your list is only displaying 1 of the 2 items from your source. There are 2 easy ways to fix this depending on your source:

**Source never changes once UI is shown**

In this case you can simply make sure your source is fully populated before you initialize your Window.

```
public class MainWindow {
    public List <string> People { get; set; }

    public MainWindow () {
        People = new List <string> ();

        //fancy code here that fully populates People

        InitializeComponent ();
    }
}
```

**Source can change once UI is shown**

In this case you can change your source to be or inherit from [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) which notifies targets when its collection is changed.

```
public class MainWindow {
    public ObservableCollection <string> People { get; set; }

    public MainWindow () {
        People = new ObservableCollection <string> ();
        InitializeComponent ();

        People.Add ("new person");

        //other code that modifies People after components are initialized
    }
}
```

There are more ways but these 2 are the really easy ones.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have properly set the ListView's View property.
In a simple ListView, items are displayed on multiple lines if the view is 'Details'